# Servo coupler size needed

Tags: arduino, stepper-motor, rcservo

Hey all I would like to know what type of coupler I would need for this type of [servo](https://us.banggood.com/Wholesale-Warehouse-JX-PDI-6221MG-20KG-Large-Torque-Digital-Coreless-Servo-For-RC-Model-wp-Usa-973947.html?rmmds=myorder)?

[image]

The specs are:

[image]

I'm guessing that the **25T** means it has 25 teeth in the part that holds the adapters?

So I would guess I would need something like this?

[image]

But I also would like to know what **size** those are called for my servo. I've seen them advertised as 5mm to 8mm. 6mm to 8mm, etc etc so I don't know if those are going to work? Some also just have a smooth round hole without the **teeth** and I'm not sure if that's something I could use as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RC Servos come with several different styles of exit shafts (often called splines due to the teeth that are cut into them).  There are quite a few different styles.  Tooth count (yes, 25T means 25 tooth) is a major indicator of the styles; but, some styles have the same tooth count but different diameter so you cannot go by tooth count alone.

Two of the most popular RC Servo Manufacturers are [HiTEC](http://hitecrcd.com/) and [Futaba](http://www.futabarc.com/)
The companies make motors with several different spline/shaft sizes

Futaba's most common sizes are 1F(15 tooth),2F(21 tooth),3F(25 tooth),4F(25 tooth)[image: Futaba Splines]

HiTEK's most common sizes are A1(15 tooth),B1(25 tooth),C1(24 tooth),D1(15 tooth) [image: HiTEK Splines]

HiTEK also some motors with an H25T spline which matches the popular Futaba 3F spline.

I can't tell for sure; but, it looks like the JX Servo uses a  25T (probably 3F-style) spline.

[ServoCity](https://www.servocity.com/) lists has several different [Servo Couplers](https://www.servocity.com/servos/servo-accessories/servo-attachments/couplers)

[This coupler](https://www.servocity.com/25t-futaba-set-screw-shaft-coupler) is a 3F style